# C# 8 switch expression: Handle multiple cases at once?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, c#-8.0, switch-expression

C# 8 introduced pattern matching, and I already found good places to use it, like this one:

```cs
private static GameType UpdateGameType(GameType gameType)
{
    switch (gameType)
    {
        case GameType.RoyalBattleLegacy:
        case GameType.RoyalBattleNew:
            return GameType.RoyalBattle;
        case GameType.FfaLegacy:
        case GameType.FfaNew:
            return GameType.Ffa;
        default:
            return gameType;
    }
}
```

which then becomes

```cs
private static GameType UpdateGameType(GameType gameType) => gameType switch
{
    GameType.RoyalBattleLegacy => GameType.RoyalBattle,
    GameType.RoyalBattleNew => GameType.RoyalBattle,
    GameType.FfaLegacy => GameType.Ffa,
    GameType.FfaNew => GameType.Ffa,
    _ => gameType;
};
```

However, you can see I now have to mention `GameType.RoyalBattle` and `GameType.Ffa` twice. Is there a way to handle multiple cases at once in pattern matching? I'm thinking of anything like this, but it is not valid syntax:

```cs
private static GameType UpdateGameType(GameType gameType) => gameType switch
{
    GameType.RoyalBattleLegacy, GameType.RoyalBattleNew => GameType.RoyalBattle,
    GameType.FfaLegacy, GameType.FfaNew => GameType.Ffa,
    _ => gameType;
};
```

I also tried things like

```cs
[GameType.RoyalBattleLegacy, GameType.RoyalBattleNew] => GameType.RoyalBattle
```

or

```cs
GameType.FfaLegacy || GameType.FfaNew => GameType.Ffa
```

but none are valid.

Also did not find any example on this. Is it even supported?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of C#9, you can do exactly what you wanted via "disjunctive `or`" patterns:

```
private static GameType UpdateGameType(GameType gameType) => gameType switch
{
    GameType.RoyalBattleLegacy or GameType.RoyalBattleNew => GameType.RoyalBattle,
    GameType.FfaLegacy or GameType.FfaNew => GameType.Ffa,
    _ => gameType;
};
```

Further reading:

- [What's new in C# 9.0: pattern matching enhancements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements)
- [Patterns C# reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns)

Comment: You're absolutely right! Indeed I've been using it since it was introduced, good call to add a newer answer here.

Answer (score 5):

You can eventually use [**var** pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#var-pattern) combined with [case guard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#switch-expression) ([**when** clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#when-clauses-in-case-expressions)). Not sure if it is better than the variant with duplicate return values, but here it is:

```cs
private static GameType UpdateGameType(GameType gameType) => gameType switch
{
    var v when v == GameType.RoyalBattleLegacy || v == GameType.RoyalBattleNew
        => GameType.RoyalBattle,
    var v when v == GameType.FfaLegacy || v == GameType.FfaNew
        => GameType.Ffa,
    _ => gameType
};
```

Comment: That's probably the best solution for now, even if a bit unreadable (C#'s fault). Not sure if I'll actually use it in the source, but this answers my question nicely. :)

Comment: You don't need to assign to a variable v since you are doing nothing with it. It just can be `_ when gameType == GameType.RoyalBattleLegacy || gameType == GameType.RoyalBattleNew`

Comment: @Eli is right - multiple discards with "when" case guard are more suitable and shorter.

Comment: @Alex34758 True. But this is quite old (and now obsoleted) answer I don't see a reason for updating. The modern approach is provided in the currently accepted answer.